MAUI Splash Screen Image not loading correctly in Android
I have a rectangular svg Image, that I want to use as a splash screen. It is coming correctly on iOS , but is very distorted on Android. Is there a way to make it right?
Android Splash Screen : Link Droid
iOS Splash Screen : Link iOS
Splash Logo : Link Splash
I have tried with Just logo but that also gets distorted, is there a way to add the rectangular Splash Screen on android?

Please upload the images here, don't post links to images, because the links might break.

What's the version of your android device? And have you tried to update the nugets of your app to the latest ones?

@JessieZhang-MSFT Android 14, and yes all the MAUI nugets are latest

You can try to set the base size for your splash screen image.

@JessieZhang-MSFT Setting base size is not helping. I have tried that

How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?
